SwiftUI drag & drop implementation triggers EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception
I've been struggling with a generic EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception while implementing drag & drop in SwiftUI, even after dumbing it all the way down to the bare minimum it's still happening and I can't get my head around why.
In the example below I wan't to drag the blue rectangle and move it behind the second orange box. It works as long as I drop it on the second orange box, but once I hover over the orange box and exit the box with the mouse it crashes once releasing the dragged blue rectangle. Even though the blue rectangle moved/animated to the correct position.
Anybody who has got a hunch or knows why this would trigger the exception? It has something to do with dropping the blue rectangle outside a view tagged with the onDrop view modifier, but I'm missing something.

import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {

    @State var index = 0

    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Color.orange
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: MinimalDropDelegate(destinationIndex: 0, index: $index))

            if index == 0 {
                Color.cyan
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 100)
                    .onDrag {
                        NSItemProvider()
                    }
            }

            Color.orange
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: MinimalDropDelegate(destinationIndex: 1, index: $index))

            if index == 1 {
                Color.cyan
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 100)
                    .onDrag {
                        NSItemProvider()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MinimalDropDelegate: DropDelegate {

    let destinationIndex: Int
    @Binding var index: Int

    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        .init(operation: .move)
    }

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        true
    }

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        withAnimation {
            index = destinationIndex
        }
    }
}


Binding is only for SwiftUI Views
